# Tcl find if a variable exists in object instance

Tags: variables, object, tcl

In a namespace, it is very easy, for the sake of lazy evaluation, find if a namespace variable exists, from within the namespace:

```
info exists [ namespace current]::<var name>
```

How can I achieve the same for an instance of  class, using Tcl OO?
I use TCL 8.6
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
info exists [self namespace]::<var name>
```

or

```
expr {<var name> in [info class variables <class name>]}

if {<var name> in [info class variables <class name>]} {
    ...
}
```

Documentation:
[expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[in (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm),
[self (class configuration prefix)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/define.htm),
[self](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/self.htm)